# C++ bit manipulation

Tags: c++, unicode, bit-shift

I am trying to extract character value from UTF-8 format. Suppose I have two characters, and I extract 5 bits from first character => 10111 and 6 bits from another character => 010000

so

```
ch1 = 10111;
ch2 = 010000;
```

**how would I combine them to form 10111010000 and output its hex as 0x5d0?** Do I need to shift or is there an easier way to do this, because checking the documentation `write` appear to be able to read characters sequentially, is there a similar function like this? Also, it appears I would need a char buffer since 10111010000 is 11 bits long. Does any know how to go about this?

Comment: How about using `union` ? You may have to take extra care as their alignment might be platform dependent.

Comment: @iammilind how would I use union? Could you elaborate in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use shifting, plus the `|` or `|=` operator.

```
unsigned int ch3 = (ch1 << 6) | ch2;
// ch3 = 0000010111010000
```

I'm assuming here that an `unsigned int` is 16 bits.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I need up to 21 bits to read largest utf8. How would I do that?

Comment: And then, to print in hex, `std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex;`

Comment: @Mark I'd look into [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/).  Alternatively, you can use an `unsigned long int`, which is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits.

Comment: @Mark, you can check the size of unsigned int with `sizeof`. On my platform, on C++, unsigned int is 4 bytes (strictly speaking, 4 chars), which is 32 bits, so it is OK for your purposes. Or do you need to combine up to 2*21 bits?

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely need to use shift and OR.

First, declare an unsigned integer type of the right size. I like the C99 types defined in stdint.h but your C++ compiler may not have them. If you don't have `uint16_t` then you can use `unsigned short`. That is 16 bits wide and can hold 11 bits.

Then you would figure out which bits go into the high bits. It looks like it should be:

```
unsigned short ch1 = 0x17;
unsigned short ch2 = 0x10;
unsigned short result = (ch1 << 6) | ch2;
```

Comment: The largest extraction takes up to 21 bits. Do I need a char buffer[]?

Comment: @Mark, no, see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc. According to that, the standard requires `unsigned long` to be 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

## 1: for combining them together:

```
char bytes[2] = { 0x17, 0x10 }; // for example

unsigned short result = 0;      // 00000000  00000000
result = bytes[0] << 6;         // 101 11000000
result |= bytes[1];             // 101 11010000
```

## 2: for printing it out as hex

```
std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex << <what you want to print>;
```

in this case:

```
std::cout << std::showbase << std::hex << result
// output: 0x5d0 if it is little-endian, it depends on your operating system
```

Answer (score 0):

First, from K&R: "Almost everything about bitfields is implementation dependent".

The following works on MS Visual Studio 2008:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct bitbag {
    unsigned int ch2 : 6;
    unsigned int ch1 : 6;
};

int main ()
{
    struct bitbag bits;

    memset(&bits, 0, sizeof(bits));

    bits.ch1 = 0x17;    // 010111
    bits.ch2 = 0x10;    // 010000

    printf ("0x%06x 0x%06x\n", bits.ch1, bits.ch2);
    printf ("0x%0x\n", bits);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

```
0x000017 0x000010
0x5d0
```

However I could not guarentee that it will work in the same way in all compilers.  Note the `memset` which initialises any padding to zero.

Comment: And doing a printf on a struct ... no guarantees that will work.

Comment: Furthermore, you'd need "variable bitwidths" for UTF-8, the bit layout depends on the first byte. And those don't exist at all.